# MSBuild Using Take Fails to load assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I am attempting to use MSBuild and the YUICompressor for .NET to compress my js and css files upon build.

I am following the documentation found [here](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visual%20Studio%20Post-build%20Event%20example&ProjectName=yuicompressor) and [here](http://blackriverweb.com/2011/09/compressing-css-with-yui-compressor-for-net/)

When I try to build, I am getting the following error:

```
Error   4   The "CompressorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Apps\MyApp\packages\YUICompressor.NET.1.7.0.0\lib\net35\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll.
```

Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its 
dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
 Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

My post build command is as such:

```
$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=$(ConfigurationName) "$(ProjectDir)MSBuild\MSBuildSettings.xml"
```

Any ideas on why this may be occuring? The assemblies seem to be in the correct directories.

Comment: I suppose..The project fails to build. I am attempting to create a post-build event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this... I needed to reference a different dll in the UsingTask setting

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="CompressorTask" AssemblyFile="Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MSBuildTask.dll" />
```

Please see the sample application referenced in the downloads section of http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/